# Elasticsearch: Aggregation returns garbage values sometimes

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm relatively new to Elasticsearch. I'd really be grateful if anyone can help me with an issue in the aggregation query. I have the default setup of 5 clusters on a single node. My index contains the mapping as follows:

```
    mapping = {
      "my_index": {
        "date_detection": False,
        "dynamic_templates": [{
          "string_fields": {
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string",
              "fields": {
                "raw": {
                  "index": "not_analyzed",
                  "ignore_above": 256,
                  "type": "string"
                }
              }
            },
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "match": "*"
          }
        }]
      }
    }
```

I have already created aggregation queries for my requirement as follows:

```
records = es.search(index="my_index",doc_type="marksheet",body={ "aggs": { "student_name": { "terms": { "field": "name.raw","order": { "total_score" : "desc" } }, "aggs": { "total_score": { "sum": { "field": "score" } } } } } } )
```

This query works perfectly fine, just as i need it, most of the times. But sometimes, due to reasons unknown, this same query returns very large or very small results, like: **1.4e-322**.

I haven't been able to find out a proper reason as to why this would happen on its own. Would really appreciate it someone could help me out with this. Thank You!

UPDATE:

After running the following aggregation:

```
{"aggs":{"score_stats":{"stats":{"field":"score"}}}}
```

I get the results in the aggregation key as:

```
{u'score_stats': {u'count': 1186, u'max': 5e-323, u'sum': 4.5187e-320, u'avg': 4e-323, u'min': 2e-323}}
```

UPDATE 2:

After running the query as the one below:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/my_index/marksheet/_search?_source=score&size=100&pretty&filter_p‌​ath=hits.hits.score
```

The hits key in the output is as follows:

```
"hits" : [ {
  "_index" : "my_index",
  "_type" : "marksheet",
  "_id" : "AU61alGT0VlANyomm3HT",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source":{"score":10}
}, {
  "_index" : "my_index",
  "_type" : "marksheet",
  "_id" : "AU61alGV0VlANyomm3HV",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source":{"score":10}
}, {
  "_index" : "my_index",
  "_type" : "marksheet",
  "_id" : "AU61alGa0VlANyomm3Ha",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source":{"score":8}
}, {
  "_index" : "my_index",
  "_type" : "marksheet",
  "_id" : "AU61alGf0VlANyomm3Hh",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source":{"score":8}
}, {
  "_index" : "my_index",
  "_type" : "marksheet",
  "_id" : "AU61alGk0VlANyomm3Hn",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source":{"score":6}
}, {
  "_index" : "my_index",
  "_type" : "marksheet",
  "_id" : "AU61alGp0VlANyomm3Hu",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source":{"score":10}
}, {
  "_index" : "my_index",
  "_type" : "marksheet",
  "_id" : "AU61alGu0VlANyomm3H0",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source":{"score":10}
}, {
  "_index" : "my_index",
  "_type" : "marksheet",
  "_id" : "AU61alGz0VlANyomm3H7",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source":{"score":10}
}, {
  "_index" : "my_index",
  "_type" : "marksheet",
  "_id" : "AU61alHA0VlANyomm3IN",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source":{"score":8}
}, {
  "_index" : "my_index",
  "_type" : "marksheet",
  "_id" : "AU61alHD0VlANyomm3IR",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source":{"score":10}
},
...
```

Comment: What kind of values do your `score` fields contain?

Comment: @Val When i check the mapping using GET, the "score" field is of type "long".

Comment: Ok, can you also tell what kind of values are you feeding in?

Comment: I have values like: 8, 10, 6, etc.

Comment: And you're certain that all documents have a value for that field?

Comment: Yes. All of my documents do have a score field.

Comment: Can you try to run this aggregation and update your question with the results: `{"aggs":{"score_stats":{"stats":{"field":"score"}}}}`. I'm interested in the `min` and `max` values. Thx

Comment: @Val I've updated my question with the results. Please check. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, from what I can see, there are no super large `score` values, but only super small ones. Can you paste the few values you get when running this: `curl -XGET localhost:9200/my_index/marksheet/_search?_source=score&size=100&pretty&filter_path=hits.hits.score`

Comment: @Val I've update the question with the results again.